# How to increase page speed in Microsoft edge

Tags: pagespeed, microsoft-edge

Since the new Microsoft browser, Edge, has been released the major issue has been with page speed. Are there any hacks so that we can increase the page speed in Microsoft Edge?
The website which I have created uses the minified files but even then MS edge takes long time to open the page.

Comment: you can use gzip compression

Comment: @VikasGautam I have used gulp to minify files and using that minify files but then also page takes very long time to render the content

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a way to speed up your page by not doing any programming at all. If you have a valid domain, you could sign up to https://cloudflare.com and enable the option to compress web content which will speed up your site. This is just a suggestion.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

- concatenate all js files to one file and then minify it
- concatenate all css files to one file and then minify it
- minify html, and low the image quality might help a bit as well
- for common libs, eg jquery, use CDN addrs
  eg:

chances are other websites use the same lib the same way so the browser does not need to download again.

the points above would help a bit. If it's only slow on Edge, it also could be that there is some javescript code Edge does not like.